# Auto resize panels when screen size changed in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a new in Unity, and I have an issue in resizing panels when screen size changed, I have 3 panels in big panel each panel has 1 active image and 2 hidden images and I want to not be intersected or have huge padding when screen size changed.

the following GIF shows my scenario.

[image]

So, how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is really complex question, you need these 3 panels will not intersect? Check this - https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html, this is not the best solution but the layout group can change size and padding dynamically.

Comment: Great, your response is really useful, I solved it with vertical layout group, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html, this component allow you to change size and padding for group of objects.